# With Kohana 3, how can I get the last insert ID from the Database class?

Tags: php, mysql, kohana, kohana-3, lastinsertid

I have been through a fair bit of the code in modules/database/classes/ but still have not found how to return the last insert Id.

How do I get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

query() method returns an array contains last inset id and number of rows affected

the actual code located at lines 201-208 at mysql.php (kohana v3.0.3)

Comment: What's usage? This does not work (method does not exist) `DB::query(Database::INSERT, $query)->execute()->query()`

Comment: take a look what DB::query(Database::INSERT, $query)->execute() returns

Comment: BTW, I just looked over my code from my first comment - whoops! What was I thinking?